# Accessing Project asset using Project_lib on cloud notebook in IBM Watson Studio

Tags: python-3.x, db2, ibm-cloud, project

using the code:

```
import project_lib

project = project_lib.Project()
```

I tried to use the module "project_lib" in the IBM cloud Pak for data notebook but got the error:
`"RuntimeError: Failed to GET project, status: 401"`.
The package is for accessing the assets (i.e. files) of my projects.

I tried to ask questions on IBM's website or customer services but could not find any valid solution yet. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameters `project_id` and `access_token` into the `Project` function to make it work.

```
from project_lib import Project

project = Project(project_id='YOUR_PROJECT_ID', project_access_token='YOUR_PROJECT_TOKEN')
```